# $_POST Undefined index: Error

Tags: php, post, server-side

The Form:

```
<form action="/HW2/controllers/login.php" id = "login-box" method = "post">
        Username: <input type="text" name='user'><br>
        Password: <input type="text" name='pwd'><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

The Action:

```
<?php
require("../config/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])){
    if(strcmp($_POST['user'], USERNAME) == 0 && strcmp($_POST['pwd'], 
        PASSWORD) == 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
        echo "success";
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loggedin");
    }else{
        print_r("Sorry, your username and/or password are invalid. Try Again?");
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loginPage");
        }
}else{
    print_r("Post data not sent.");
}
?>
```

I've tried numerous different approaches and all result in "Post data not sent."(aka "Undefined index:" if I try to access the $_POST values) Been trying to find what I messed up for a good few hours now, any help is appreciated, I'm a total scrub at php, it's likely something incredibly simple and stupid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should your session before including config.php file.

Comment: your form works for me. Maybe, something is wrong in config.php. Try to remove it and var_dump($_POST) before `if`;

Comment: As an aside it seems you are storing an unencrypted password locally (in your PASSWORD constant). You shouldn't have access to the user's unencrypted password if you want to make a safe application.

Comment: make sure the path you provided is correct. if both the files i.e. the "file whose code has been shared" here and "login.php file" are in the same directory then you dont need to add the whole path at avtion there. A mistake i made when i started php.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need use last  "else  "

use only

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])){
if(strcmp($_POST['user'], USERNAME) == 0 && strcmp($_POST['pwd'], 
    PASSWORD) == 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
    echo "success";
    //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loggedin");
}else{
    print_r("Sorry, your username and/or password are invalid. Try Again?");
    //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loginPage");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require("../config/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])){
    if(strcmp($_POST['user'], USERNAME) == 0 && strcmp($_POST['pwd'], 
        PASSWORD) == 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
        echo "success";
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loggedin");
    }else{
        print_r("Sorry, your username and/or password are invalid. Try Again?");
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loginPage");
        }
}else{
    print_r("Post data not sent.");
}
?>
```

**error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);** shows error but hides notices. The undefined index shows that the $_POST variable was called without having a value so this is the first option. The second option is to revise the code.

The view:

```
<form action="/HW2/controllers/login.php" id = "login-box" method = "post">
        Username: <input type="text" name='user'><br>
        Password: <input type="text" name='pwd'><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
require("../config/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(strcmp($_POST['user'], USERNAME) == 0 && strcmp($_POST['pwd'], 
        PASSWORD) == 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
        echo "success";
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loggedin");
    }else{
        print_r("Sorry, your username and/or password are invalid. Try Again?");
        //header("location: /HW2/index.php?view=loginPage");
        }
}else{
    print_r("Post data not sent.");
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for your answers everyone, turns out that my code was working fine after I restarted my computer and took a nap.

My guess was that either chrome or apache was mishandling the $_POST variables, but I'm not very experienced so I'm just spitballing. Either way my code is doing what I want now.

Thanks for the help anyways!